# The use of the verb thank in the progressive form

Tags: questions, present-continuous

Can I use the verb "to thank" in the present continuous (progressive) form such as in "Are you thanking me...? ( I am a nonnative speaker of English)

Comment: That's fine, perfectly good English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. 
For example: James gives Tom a lift home from work in his car. James also lets Tom borrow some money to get some food. The next day Tom says thank you to James. James asks Tom, "Are you thanking me for the lift or for the money?" Tom replies, "Oh - for both."
You could also hear "Are you saying thank you for the lift or the money?", although to my ears, the original progressive use sounds more natural.